# nHibernate stored procedure call to return list of data

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures

I want to call the stored procedure from the application with out specifying anything in the mapping file my stored procedure return is a list.

```
public IList<INewItem> GetItemsByfilter(IList<object> Filters)
{
    // call sp with out using the mapping file sp returns a dataset
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IList results = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec myStoredProcedure").List();
```

Or get the raw `IDbConnection` from `session.Connection` and use ADO.NET to run the stored procedure.